# How can I find out if my Zone file is different around nameservers?

Tags: dns-zone, email-bounces

It appears my zone file is sometimes randomly empty for some DNS servers. I've had the domain for over a decade. This issue has infrequently appeared over the last five years.

The zone file (superformula.com) is hosted with AWS now.  I have changed a the name servers a few times over the last ten years.

I notice it when I get bouncebacks trying to send an email.

`450 4.1.8 : Sender address rejected: Domain not found`

Im using Google's SMTP server.

It will occasionally resolve itself.  And there are other servers that no longer receive from my domain, like linkedin.com and Apple's me.com email service.

How can I diagnose why some DNS servers are not finding my A or MX records and others are working fine?

Comment: You zone file isn't hosted on any DNS servers other than your name servers. They may have problems resolving your records from your name servers, but they don't store a copy of your zone. If you provide the domain name we may be able to help you figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: `Domain not found` I'm guessing that was a query directly against the name servers for the provider that is hosting the zone. Is there anything different or atypical about the zone?

Comment: A suggestion: when reporting issues, report only facts, symptoms, with as detailed error message, screenshot. logs etc as possible, rather than  report "what you think". Any proof that zone file is empty?

Comment: I wonder if other nameservers are holding onto my zone?  I have switched a few times over the last decade.  I will add my domain to the original question.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! In many cases mentioning the actual domain name is essential for the community to be able to help diagnose DNS issues. Thank you for adding yours. Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions. - At the moment all listed name servers for your domain respond with a `REFUSED` error when querying  them for your domain See for example  https://dnsviz.net/d/superformula.com/dnssec/  which suggest that your AWS Route 53 settings for your domain are incorrect

Comment: No other name servers are "holding onto" your zone because no other name servers host your zone. Your name servers hold your zone. Based on this check, you definitely have some issues at the parent servers and at your name servers. - https://intodns.com/superformula.com

Comment: Thank you.  I modified the NS records to be what Route53 was listing for my domain. I still see some warnings in there.  I will continue to monitor.